# Go showing strange behavior in infinite loop

Tags: go, channel

I am having very strange behavior in my Go code.  The overall gist is that when I have

```
for {
  if messagesRecieved == l {
    break
  }
  select {
  case result := <-results:
    newWords[result.index] = result.word
    messagesRecieved += 1
  default:
    // fmt.Printf("messagesRecieved: %v\n", messagesRecieved)
    if i != l {
      request := Request{word: words[i], index: i, thesaurus_word: results}
      requests <- request
      i += 1
    }
  }
}
```

the program freezes and fails to advance, but when I uncomment out the fmt.Printf command, then the program works fine.  You can see the entire code [here](https://github.com/elju/shaker.go/blob/9c804d1e8f85665cfe6bda043ff6167167b1ef50/shaker.go). does anyone know what's causing this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in version 1.1.2 (the current release) has still only the original (since initial release) cooperative scheduling of goroutines. The compiler improves the behavior by inserting scheduling points. Inferred from the memory model they are next to channel operations. Additionaly also in some well known, but intentionally undocumented places, such as where I/O occurs. The last explains why uncommenting `fmt.Printf` changes the behavior of your program. And, BTW, the Go tip version now sports a preemptive scheduler.

Your code keeps one of your goroutines busy going through the default select case. As there are no other scheduling points w/o the print, no other goroutine has a chance to make progress (assuming default GOMAXPROCS=1).

I recommend to rewrite the logic of the program in a way which avoids spinning (busy waiting). One possible approach is to use a channel send in the default case. As a perhaps nice side effect of using a buffered channel for that, one gets a simple limiter from that for free.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry, this may be ignorant, but what is the Go "tip" version?  Also, where did you learn so much about the compiler?  It would be good to know where to get information about what is happening with Go at a lower level.  Thanks!

Comment: @elju: It's the bleeding edge/unstable/development/not finished next version of Go. If you're compiling Go from sources, you can get it by `hg pull && hg update default && ./all.bash` in the `go/src` directory. See also tip.golang.org where the godocs for that version are available, ie. including any changes which made it to the next planned version. Of course, the tip version is not recommended for production.